# How is the following code in Python in C#?

Tags: c#, python, hash

How is the following code in Python in C#?

I need to get the hash generated by this code to send to http://en.thesubdb.com/api/ to get a subititle, but my code is in C #.

```
def get_hash(name):
    readsize = 64 * 1024
    with open(name, 'rb') as f:
        size = os.path.getsize(name)
        data = f.read(readsize)
        f.seek(-readsize, os.SEEK_END)
        data += f.read(readsize)
    return hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
```

- Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: If you're not willing to translate the python code to C# yourself, maybe you could just add ironpython to your project and invoke that python code through that...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is a Question and Answer site, not a code translation service. Please try to translate the code yourself first, then come to us when you are stuck, making sure to show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), preferably in the form of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm trying to hours, until I decided to put here.

Comment: Looks like `size` is never used. And with just a quick look I think it reads the file backwards then do a `md5` of that.

Comment: I saw, but dont know how python work imagined an abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetHash( string caminho ) {
        const int bytesToRead = 64 * 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead * 2];
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider( );
        using( var md52 = MD5.Create( ) ) {
            using( var stream = new FileStream( caminho, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read ) ) {
                for( int i = 0; i < bytesToRead; i++ ) {
                    buffer[i] = (byte)stream.ReadByte( );
                }

                stream.Seek( -bytesToRead, SeekOrigin.End );

                for( int i = bytesToRead; i < bytesToRead * 2; i++ ) {
                    buffer[i] = (byte)stream.ReadByte( );
                }
                return BitConverter.ToString( md52.ComputeHash( buffer ) ).Replace( "-", "" ).ToLower( );
            }
        }          
    }
```

Reading byte by byte I got. For those who need that is code.